# What is the Xpath expression that involves multiple exclusions?

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have html like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="content"> 
    <span>some content</span>
    <div id="s1">
     <p> some text </p>
    </div>
    <h2 id="sec1">
      <span> some text </span>
      <p> some text </p>
    </h2>
    <h2 id="sec1">
      <span> some text </span>
      <div> some more text </div> 
      <p> some text </p>
    </h2>
    <h2 id="sec2">
      <span> do not select me some text </span>
      <div> do not select me some more text </div> 
      <p> do not select me some text </p>
    </h2>
    <h2 id="sec3">
      <span> do not select me some text </span>
      <div> do not select me some more text </div> 
      <p> do not select me some text </p>
    </h2>
   </div>
 </div>
```

What is the XPath expression that selects all text node except those that are under h2 id=sec2 and h2 id=sec3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally, "all text node except those that are under h2 id=sec2 and h2 id=sec3":

```
//text()[not(ancestor::h2[@id='sec2' or @id='sec3'])]
```

However I suspect that you don't really want that, because you would be losing the `<span>` and `<p>` structure. Would it be correct to infer that you want to select all the child elements of the content `<div>`, except for the `<h2>`s whose id's are sec2 and sec3? If so,

```
/div/div[@id = 'content']/*[not(self::h2 and (@id = 'sec2' or @id = 'sec3'))]
```

**But** you should also be aware that the text content of the `<h2>` element is merely the *title* of a section, not the whole text of the section. So it looks like by putting div's and p's inside an h2, you are not using it the way it is designed.

Comment: I simply want all text nodes that are descendants of div with id=wrap except those that are descendants of h2 with id=sec2 and id=sec3. I will test your approach and will write back.

Comment: @Alan: ok, I just wanted to check, because sometimes people say "node" when they mean "element", and even say "text node" when they mean "element that may contain text". What you're asking for would not include any elements (`<p>`, `<span>`, etc.) but would include a text node containing "some content", another containing "some text", and so on. It might also include some text nodes you don't expect, such as the whitespace between `<div id="wrap">` and `<div id="content">`, depending on your whitespace-stripping options.

Answer (score 1):

All elements under an `<h2>` (except …):

```
//h2[not(@id = 'sec2' or @id = 'sec3')]/*
```

All `<span>`, `<div>` or `<p>` elements *anywhere* (except …):

```
//*[self::span or self::div or self::p][not(parent::h2/@id = 'sec2' or parent::h2/@id = 'sec3')]
```

alternative notation (note the parens and the slightly changed predicate):

```
(//span|//div|//p)[not(parent::h2[@id = 'sec2' or @id = 'sec3'])]
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it does not work. The problem is the descendants of h2 are being selected and not excluded.

Comment: @Alan: All three XPath expressions work exactly as described (I've tested them). You must make a mistake somewhere (or your sample does not reflect the real situation).

Comment: your XPath expressions do not select any text nodes. They select elements. (If you `xsl:copy-of` those elements, you will copy their text node descendants too, but that's not the same thing.) Nevertheless in this regard, you may be doing what the OP wanted even though what he asked for was different.